# WinForms TabControl drag drop problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have two TabControls and I've implemented the ability to drag and drop tabpages between the two controls. It works great until you drag the last tabpage off one of the controls. The control then stops accepting drops and I can't put any tabpages back on that control.

The drag and drop code for one direction is below. The reverse direction is the same with the control names swapped.

```
// Source TabControl
private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) 
    this.tabControl1.DoDragDrop(this.tabControl1.SelectedTab, DragDropEffects.All);
}

//Target TabControl 
private void tabControl2_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(TabPage))) 
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
  else 
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None; 
} 

private void tabControl2_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e) 
{
  TabPage DropTab = (TabPage)(e.Data.GetData(typeof(TabPage))); 
  if (tabControl2.SelectedTab != DropTab)
    this.tabControl2.TabPages.Add (DropTab); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override `WndProc` in the TabControl and turn `HTTRANSPARENT` into `HTCLIENT` in the `WM_NCHITTEST` message.

For example:

```
const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
const int HTTRANSPARENT = -1;
const int HTCLIENT = 1;

//The default hit-test for a TabControl's
//background is HTTRANSPARENT, preventing
//me from receiving mouse and drag events
//over the background.  I catch this and 
//replace HTTRANSPARENT with HTCLIENT to 
//allow the user to drag over us when we 
//have no TabPages.
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST) {
        if (m.Result.ToInt32() == HTTRANSPARENT)
            m.Result = new IntPtr(HTCLIENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed the problem thanks!   How did you figure this out?

Comment: @Kevin: This bit me two years ago.  I can't remember whether I Googled it or used Spy++.

Comment: This is why stackoverflow is great! I did search with google for hours and tried lots of other things for more hours.

Comment: I'm using the exact same code as @KevinGale but I can't get your fix to work for me.  In lieu of any actual clue about how to implement it I just copied and pasted your code into my Form1 class.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JonnyP: You need to put this in a `TabControl` class.

Comment: So I should overwrite part of the built-in TabControl class?  How can I override just portions of that class from within my project?

Comment: Make your own class that inherits `TabControl`

Comment: @SLaks - Just finished that a few seconds ago.  Thanks :)